# How to return UIImage with certain alpha

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, alpha

I am writing a method that takes a image and a alpha value then return a uiimage with that alpha value.

I have found some code like this

```
+ (UIImage *)imageByApplyingAlpha:(UIImage*) originalImage andAlpha:(CGFloat) alpha {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, NO, 0.0f);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height);

    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);

    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, alpha);

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, originalImage.CGImage);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

but this only work on single image. It will generate malformed GIF when I use the returned image to form GIF.

Please help me to find a easy way to get UIImage with alpha.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the GIF format doesn't support alpha channels](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/png-gif), so you won't be able to set alpha values on one. Transparency in GIF uses [index transparency](http://www.idux.com/2011/02/27/what-are-index-and-alpha-transparency/), which is all or nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any way to generate gif with transition between images? I am writing a app to synthesis different photos from gallery.